# How do I display an error message for incorrect input?

Tags: java, error-handling

I am trying to print a message when an incorrect input is entered. Such as a variable being set as an integer but the user inputs a string. I have attached my code below. I cannot figure out how to cover this exception.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Paint1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    double wallHeight = 0.0;
    double wallWidth = 0.0;
    double wallArea = 0.0;
    double gallonsPaintNeeded = 0.0;
    
    final double squareFeetPerGallons = 350.0;
    
    // Implement a do-while loop to ensure input is valid
    // Prompt user to input wall's height
   do {
        System.out.println("Enter wall height (feet): ");
        wallHeight = scnr.nextDouble();
   } while (wallHeight <= 0);

    // Implement a do-while loop to ensure input is valid
    // Prompt user to input wall's width
   do {
       System.out.println("Enter wall width (feet): ");
       wallWidth = scnr.nextDouble();
   } while (wallWidth <= 0);

    // Calculate and output wall area
    wallArea = wallHeight * wallWidth;
    System.out.println("Wall area: " + wallArea + " square feet");

    // Calculate and output the amount of paint (in gallons) needed to paint the wall
    gallonsPaintNeeded = wallArea/squareFeetPerGallons;
    System.out.println("Paint needed: " + gallonsPaintNeeded + " gallons");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a while loop to have the user input something until I get the desired result. To determine whether or not the user entered the correct thing in this case, put a try/catch around `scnr.nextDouble()`. The exception you're looking for is `InputMismatchException`. This is an example that I made:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
double value;
while(true) {
    System.out.print("Enter a double: ");
    try {
        value = scanner.nextDouble();
        break;
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("That is not a valid input. Please try again.");
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
System.out.println("The double entered was " + value);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try/catch block, and write something like `System.err.println("wrong input");`.

An java.util.InputMismatchException should be thrown (and caught!)